# How do I define a sequence to do a form post in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: forms, http, post, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm trying to define a sequence to do a HTTP post. I can't get my post variables to be sent in the request. I have

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="CDN" trace="enable">
    <property name="messageType" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
   <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="POST" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
   <send>
       <endpoint>
          <address uri="http://posttestserver.com/post.php"/>
          <property name="foo" value="bar" scope="axis2"/>
       </endpoint>
   </send>
</sequence>
```

Comment: what is the question/issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use payload factory to set the post body. Use some thing like following according to your need

```xml
     <payloadFactory>
        <format>
           <m0:getQuote xmlns:m0="http://services.samples">
              <m0:request>
                 <m0:symbol>$1</m0:symbol>
              </m0:request>
           </m0:getQuote>
        </format>
        <args>
           <arg expression="get-property('uri.var.symbol')"/>
        </args>
     </payloadFactory>
```

You have to change the following lines as you need

```
     <arg expression="get-property('uri.var.symbol')"/>
```

Please look http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/PayloadFactory+Mediator

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide answers in detail